# Subclass implements its own protocol delegate

Tags: objective-c, inheritance, objective-c-protocol

I am new to iOS, don't know if this is possible or not.

Basically I have two classes Parent and Child.

Parent has a delegate which conforms to ParentProtocol. However, the delegate in Child not only conforms to ParentProtocol, but also another ChildProtocol.

So is it possible to do the following?

```
@interface Parent {
  @property (nonatomic, unsafe_unretained) id<ParentProtocol> delegate;
}

@interface Child : Parent {
  @property (nonatomic, unsafe_unretained) id<ParentProtocol, ChildProtocol> delegate;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this is valid code.  This amounts to declaring the methods

```
- (id<ParentProtocol>)delegate;
- (void)setDelegate:(id<ParentProtocol>)delegate;
```

in the `Parent` interface and declaring methods for the same selectors (`-delegate` and `-setDelegate`) in the `Child` interface

```
- (id<ParentProtocol, ChildProtocol>)delegate;
- (void)setDelegate:(id<ParentProtocol, ChildProtocol>)delegate;
```

This is permissible (and causes no warnings) because `id<ParentProtocol>` and `id<ParentProtocol, ChildProtocol>` are compatible types.  (Contrast this to the situation where in `Child`'s declaration you declare `delegate` to be of type `NSArray *`.  You'll get the warning `Property type 'NSArray *' is incompatible with type 'id<ParentProtocol>' inherited from 'Parent'`.)

By the way, it is worth noting that you can define `ChildProtocol` to inherit from `ParentProtocol` by writing

```
@protocol ParentProtocol <NSObject>
//....
@end
```

and

```
@protocol ChildProtocol <ParentProtocol>
//....
@end
```

Which in turn would allow you to write in the interface of `Child`

```
@property (nonatomic, unsafe_unretained) id<ChildProtocol>;
```

rather than

```
@property (nonatomic, unsafe_unretained) id<ParentProtocol, ChildProtocol>;
```